# sum of row values depending on the id

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the sum of adult and child in new table based on `cid` from the same table.

table sales

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+
| cid       | adult      |  child        |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
|         1 |     20     |      20       | 
|         1 |     30     |      10       |
|         1 |    100     |      35       |
|         1 |     10     |      25       |
|         2 |     40     |      10       |
|         2 |     20     |      70       |
|         2 |     30     |      60       | 
+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

desired output:

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+
| cid       | adult      |  child        |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
|         1 |     160    |       90      | 
|         2 |      90    |      140      |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

plz help me

Comment: [Group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT cid, SUM(adult) AS adult, SUM(child) AS child 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY cid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cid,sum(adult) adult, sum(child) child FROM sales GROUP BY cid
```